# Getting Job Id in a Laravel queue with Database driver

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have a laravel job which I create from a controller and some times i want to delete those jobs as the timings will be rescheduled
It is a notification job which sends notification one hour before a class and if the class is rescheduled i need to delete the jobs and insert new ones

my controller code is as below

```
$job = (new OnlineClassRemainderJob($remainder_data))->delay($value);
$id = dispatch($job);
array_push($job_ids, $id);
```

and the Job class is as shown below

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\OnlineClassRemainderMail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Mail;

class OnlineClassRemainderJob implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
protected $details;
/**
* Create a new job instance.
*
* @return void
*/
public function __construct($details)
{
$this->details = $details;

}

/**
* Execute the job.
*
* @return void
*/
public function handle()
{

Mail::to($this->details['email'])
->send(new OnlineClassRemainderMail($this->details));

}
}
```

Kindly show light how I can get the Job id so that i can save it in a database and in case of a reschedule i can remove all job ids related to that class and then dispatch new schedules

I can layout the scenario here

I am scheduling classes for example

I have a class on every day from 20th Jan to 25th Jan at 10 AM and I am scheduling a remainder mail sending job which will fire 1 hour before the class

But at certains scenario the Classes will be rescheduled and for that purpose i need to reschedule the remainders or delete and redispatch the jobs

Answer (score 1):

you need to retrun job id from job with this function `$this->job->getJobId();`

```php
class OnlineClassRemainderJob implements ShouldQueue
{
     use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       Mail::to($this->details['email'])
               ->send(new OnlineClassRemainderMail($this->details));
       retrun $this->job->getJobId();
    }
}
```

then

```php
$job = (new OnlineClassRemainderJob($remainder_data))->delay($value);
$id = dispatch($job);
array_push($job_ids, $id);
```

ref link https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Queue/Job.html#method_getJobId

Comment: I tried as you said but the $id contains the $remainder_data which i passed to the job 
i didn't get the id of the job in the job table

Comment: @AsishAntony is it uuid ? in database ?

Comment: I would like to have the id of the job row in the database so that i can delete the job row from the job table

Comment: @AsishAntony if job complete it automatically delete

Comment: please check the scenario i have given in the question now

Answer (score 0):

To take the id of a job before executing it, e.g. to dequeue it before executing it.

```php
$log = UpdateLog::create();
UpdateProduct::dispatch($log)->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
$regex = 'UpdateLog.*?id\\\\";i:'.$log->id.';';
//delete or get job before start
DB::table('jobs')->where('payload','REGEXP',$regex)->delete();
```

my job example

```php
//...
class UpdateProduct implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var UpdateLog
     */
    protected $log;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UpdateLog $log)
    {
        $this->log = $log;
    }
//...
}
```